# How to check android app connection to web server?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, webserver, connectivity

I tried to connect my android app to web server using asyncTask but i couldn't make it.
Here in code, I need to check for internet connection using asyncTask.Please provide with some code so that app connects to any webserver

I have used two java classes and two xml files.

MainActivity and greetings.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

// Variable Declaration
    Context context=this;
private RadioGroup r1,r2,r4,r3,r5;
private RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4,rb5;
private String welcome,service,clean,knowledge,visit,responses,remarks,tq;
String food,rate;
int a1,a2,a3,a4,a5;

 ProgressDialog dialog;
 EditText text;
 Button button;
 RatingBar ra1,ra2;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>9)
        {
            StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        }
        typeface();
        init();

     }
private void typeface() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.otf");
        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setTypeface(type);
    }
    // Checking Internet Connection

// Variable Initialisation
    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ra1=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating1);
        ra2=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating2);
        r1=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        r2=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
        r3=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);
        r4=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup4);
        text.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        r5=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup5);
        text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        ra1=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating1);
        ra2=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating2);
        // RadioButton Listeners
        r1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup r1, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int a=r1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rb1=(RadioButton) findViewById(a);
                welcome=rb1.getText().toString();               
            }
         });
        r2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup r2, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int b=r2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rb2=(RadioButton) findViewById(b);
                service=rb2.getText().toString();
            }
       });
        r3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup r3, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int c=r3.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rb3=(RadioButton) findViewById(c);
                clean=rb3.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        r4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup r4, int arg4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int d=r4.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rb4=(RadioButton) findViewById(d);
                knowledge=rb4.getText().toString();
            }
         });
       r5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup r5, int arg5) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int e=r5.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rb5=(RadioButton) findViewById(e);
            visit=rb5.getText().toString();
        }

       });
       ra1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ra1, float rating, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rating=ra1.getRating();
            food=String.valueOf(rating);
        }

       });
       ra2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ra2, float rating, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rating=ra2.getRating();
                rate=String.valueOf(rating);
            }

           });

            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
// Button onClick Listener
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\



        dialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Sending...");
        //Creating a new thread for sending mail
        remarks=text.getText().toString();
        final Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                sendMail();

                }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", "Connecting");
            }
        }
    });thread.start();

}
// sendMail using post method 
    protected void sendMail() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        InputStream is=null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://wertualdesigners.com/siesta/mail/mail.php");
        try {
               List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("welcome",welcome));
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service",service));
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clean",clean));
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("knowledge",knowledge));
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("visit",visit));
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("food",food));
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remarks",remarks));
               nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rate",rate));
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
               HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                is=entity.getContent();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Error","Network problem",e);
        }  try{

                        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                        String line="";
                        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                            sb.append(line +"\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        responses=sb.toString();
                        tq=responses.toString();
                        text.setText(tq);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        Intent i=new Intent(this,greetings.class);
    i.putExtra("key", tq);
    startActivity(i);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", "No response");
        }

       dialog.dismiss();

  }
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}


Greetings.java

package com.example.formapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class greetings extends Activity{
    String greet;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.greetings);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>9)
        {
            StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        }
        TextView v=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);

        Intent i=getIntent();
      greet=i.getStringExtra("key").toString();
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.otf");
    v.setTypeface(type);
    v.setText(greet);
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();

    }
}


activity_main.xml

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Feedback Form"
        android:textSize="25sp"
         />

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight=".25" >
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="3dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Did our staff make you feel welcome upon arrival?"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Yes" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="No" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Was our service prompt?"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <RadioGroup 
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup2" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Yes" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="No" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    </RadioGroup>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Was your room clean and well supplied ?"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      <RadioGroup 
          android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Yes" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="No" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    </RadioGroup>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quality of Food "
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
   <RatingBar 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:id="@+id/rating1"
          android:numStars="5"/>


            <Space android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="10dp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Were our staffs knowledgeable?"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<RadioGroup 
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup4" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">      

             <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Yes" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="No" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    </RadioGroup>

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Would you visit us again?"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

         <RadioGroup 
             android:id="@+id/radioGroup5" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:orientation="horizontal"> 

         <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Yes" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="No" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    </RadioGroup>


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="How do we rate?"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      <RatingBar 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:id="@+id/rating2"
          android:numStars="5"/>

          <Space android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"/>

       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Suggestions/Remarks"
              android:textSize="16sp" 
              android:typeface="monospace"/>

       <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" 
           android:typeface="monospace" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp" 
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Maximum 100 Words"
             android:maxLength="100" 

             android:scrollHorizontally="false"
             android:scrollbars="vertical" />

     </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight=".75">
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:text="Submit"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:shadowRadius="5"
android:typeface="monospace"
/>
   <TextView 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="We would highly appreciate your valuable feedback"  
       android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="---Greetings from siesta super stay"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout> 


greetigs.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/t"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the permissions in your manifest file? Its a very common mistake.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

After all I think the developer.android.com is the best resource and the best explanation, I suggest you walk through step by step by [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my basic HTTPS AsyncTask, with forced GZip:

```
package using_net;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import logger.AndroidLogger;
import other.GetException;
import other.PostException;

/**
 * Created by ehog on 2013.12.11..
 */
public class BaseAsyncTask<Paramets, Progress,Result> extends AsyncTask<Paramets,Progress,Result>
{
    protected Context _context;

    public BaseAsyncTask(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected String Get(String url) throws GetException
    {
        try
        {
            AndroidLogger.PushDebugMessage("Web access: "+url);
            URL realUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = realUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GetException(e);
        }
    }

    protected String Post(String url, String message_json) throws PostException
    {
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_data",message_json));
            httpost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Your.browser.header");
            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp, HTTP.UTF_8));
            httpost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(code < 200 || code >= 300) {
                networkError(code);
                return null;
            }
            InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip"))
            {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            throw new PostException(x);
        }
    }

    protected void networkError(int code) {

    }

    protected void process(Result result) {

    }

    protected void error() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Paramets... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        if(result == null) error();
        else process(result);
    }
}
```

And a specific HTTPS AsyncTask derived from above (I'm used this for reverse geocoding via OSMA):

```
package using_net;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import globals.Global_Variables;
import logger.AndroidLogger;
import model.Blitz;
import model.NominatimAddress;
import model.SerializableLatLng;
import other.PostException;

/**
 * Created by ehog on 2014.06.21..
 */
public class NominatimQuery extends  BaseAsyncTask<SerializableLatLng,Void,JSONObject>
{
    private NominatimListener _nl;

    public interface NominatimListener
    {
        void got_address(NominatimAddress a);
    }

    public NominatimQuery(Context context, NominatimListener nl)
    {
        super(context);
        _nl = nl;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(SerializableLatLng... locs)
    {
        try
        {
            SerializableLatLng loc = locs[0];
            JSONObject nominatim_result;
            nominatim_result = new JSONObject(Post(String.format("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=%s&lon=%s&zoom=19&addressdetails=1",loc.latitude,loc.longitude), null));
            JSONObject nominatim_object = nominatim_result.optJSONObject("address");
            return nominatim_object;
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            AndroidLogger.PushErrorMessage("Nominatim error! (JSON)");
            return null;
        }
        catch (PostException e)
        {
            AndroidLogger.PushErrorMessage("Nominatim error! (POST):"+e.toString());
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AndroidLogger.PushErrorMessage("Nominatim error: "+e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void process(JSONObject nominatim_address)
    {
        if (_nl != null)
        {
            NominatimAddress a = new NominatimAddress();
            String country_code = nominatim_address.optString("country_code","");
            String city = nominatim_address.optString("city","");
            String city_district = nominatim_address.optString("city_district","");
            String town = nominatim_address.optString("town","");
            String village = nominatim_address.optString("village","");
            String hamlet = nominatim_address.optString("hamlet","");
            String footway = nominatim_address.optString("footway","");
            String street = nominatim_address.optString("street","");
            String road = nominatim_address.optString("road","");
            String house_number = nominatim_address.optString("house_number","");


            if (!hamlet.equals(""))
            {
                a.Settlement = hamlet;
            }
            else if (!village.equals(""))
            {
                a.Settlement = village;
            }
            else if (!town.equals(""))
            {
                a.Settlement = town;
            }
            else if (!city.equals(""))
            {
                a.Settlement = city;
            }
            else
            {
                a.Settlement = null;
            }

            if (country_code.equals("sk") && !city_district.equals(""))
            {
                a.Settlement = city_district;
            }
            else if (!city_district.equals(""))
            {
                a.Settlement = a.Settlement + "-"+city_district;
            }

            if (!footway.equals(""))
            {
                a.Address = footway;
            }
            else if (!street.equals(""))
            {
                a.Address = street;
            }
            if (!road.equals(""))
            {
                a.Address = road;
            }

            if (!house_number.equals(""))
            {
                a.Address = a.Address +" "+house_number+".";
            }
            if (!country_code.equals(""))
            {
                a.CountryCode = country_code;
            }
            else
            {
                a.CountryCode = "empty";
            }



            _nl.got_address(a);
        }
    }

    protected void networkError(int code) {
        if(_nl != null) _nl.got_address(null);
    }

    protected void error() {
        if(_nl != null) _nl.got_address(null);
    }


}
```